# Permission plugin bukkit always returns true

Tags: java, plugins, permissions, bukkit

I never worked with a String permission plugin yet and I had some trouble getting into it:

```
public class MainPermission {

public static void givePlayerPermission(MainPlayer player){
    ServerRank rank = player.getServerRank();
    if(rank.equals(ServerRank.STONE)){
        setPermission("ADD", player, DataFiles.PermissionConf.getStringList("STONE"));
    }else if(rank.equals(ServerRank.COAL)){
        setPermission("ADD", player, DataFiles.PermissionConf.getStringList("COAL"));
    }else if(rank.equals(ServerRank.IRON)){
        setPermission("ADD", player, DataFiles.PermissionConf.getStringList("IRON"));
    }else if(rank.equals(ServerRank.GOLD)){
        setPermission("ADD", player, DataFiles.PermissionConf.getStringList("GOLD"));
    }else if(rank.equals(ServerRank.REDSTONE)){
        setPermission("ADD", player, DataFiles.PermissionConf.getStringList("REDSTONE"));
    }else if(rank.equals(ServerRank.EMERALD)){
        setPermission("ADD", player, DataFiles.PermissionConf.getStringList("EMERALD"));
    }else if(rank.equals(ServerRank.DIAMOND)){
        setPermission("ADD", player, DataFiles.PermissionConf.getString("DIAMOND"));
    }
}

public static void removePlayerPermission(MainPlayer player){
    setPermission("REMOVE", player, "*");
}

private static boolean setPermission(String type, MainPlayer player, String permission){
    if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("ADD")){
        PermissionAttachment attachment = player.getPlayer().addAttachment(MainClass.getInstance());
        attachment.setPermission(permission, true);

          //player.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "Permission " + permission + " given");

        return true;
    }else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("REMOVE")){
        PermissionAttachment attachment = player.getPlayer().addAttachment(MainClass.getInstance());
        attachment.setPermission(permission, false);

          //player.getPlayer().sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_GREEN + "Permission " + permission + " removed");

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean setPermission(String type, MainPlayer player, List<String> permission){
    for(String s : permission){
        setPermission(type, player, s);
    }
    return true;
}

public static void initFile(){
    if(!DataFiles.PermissionsFile.exists()){
        try {
            DataFiles.PermissionsFile.createNewFile();

            ArrayList<String> STONE = new ArrayList<>();
            STONE.add("bukkit.command.version");
            STONE.add("bukkit.command.plugins");
            STONE.add("bukkit.command.help");
            STONE.add("bukkit.command.tell");

            ArrayList<String> COAL = new ArrayList<>();
            COAL.add("bukkit.command.version");
            COAL.add("bukkit.command.plugins");
            COAL.add("bukkit.command.help");
            COAL.add("bukkit.command.tell");
            COAL.add("bukkit.command.list");

            ArrayList<String> IRON = new ArrayList<>();
            IRON.add("bukkit.command.version");
            IRON.add("bukkit.command.plugins");
            IRON.add("bukkit.command.help");
            IRON.add("bukkit.command.tell");
            IRON.add("bukkit.command.list");

            ArrayList<String> GOLD = new ArrayList<>();
            GOLD.add("bukkit.command.version");
            GOLD.add("bukkit.command.plugins");
            GOLD.add("bukkit.command.help");
            GOLD.add("bukkit.command.tell");
            GOLD.add("bukkit.command.list");

            ArrayList<String> REDSTONE = new ArrayList<>();
            REDSTONE.add("bukkit.command.version");
            REDSTONE.add("bukkit.command.plugins");
            REDSTONE.add("bukkit.command.help");
            REDSTONE.add("bukkit.command.tell");
            REDSTONE.add("bukkit.command.list");
            REDSTONE.add("bukkit.command.banlist");
            REDSTONE.add("bukkit.command.kick");
            REDSTONE.add("bukkit.command.kill");
            REDSTONE.add("bukkit.command.me");
            REDSTONE.add("bukkit.command.says");
            REDSTONE.add("bukkit.command.seed");
            REDSTONE.add("bukkit.command.tellraw");
            REDSTONE.add("bukkit.command.tp");
            REDSTONE.add("MainPlugin.command.entity");
            REDSTONE.add("MainPlugin.command.permission");

            ArrayList<String> EMERALD = new ArrayList<>();
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.version");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.plugins");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.help");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.tell");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.list");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.banlist");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.kick");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.kill");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.me");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.say");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.seed");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.tellraw");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.tp");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.achievement");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.ban");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.ban-ip");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.clear");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.debug");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.difficulty");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.effect");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.enchant");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.gamemode");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.give");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.pardon");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.pardon-ip");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.playsound");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.scoreboard");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.setblock");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.setidletimeout");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.summon");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.testfor");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.testforblock");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.time");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.toggledownfall");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.weather");
            EMERALD.add("bukkit.command.xp");
            EMERALD.add("MainPlugin.command.entity");
            EMERALD.add("MainPlugin.command.permission");


            DataFiles.PermissionConf.set("STONE", STONE);
            DataFiles.PermissionConf.set("COAL", COAL);
            DataFiles.PermissionConf.set("IRON", IRON);
            DataFiles.PermissionConf.set("GOLD", GOLD);
            DataFiles.PermissionConf.set("REDSTONE", REDSTONE);
            DataFiles.PermissionConf.set("EMERALD", EMERALD);
            DataFiles.PermissionConf.set("DIAMOND", "*");

            DataFiles.PermissionConf.save(DataFiles.PermissionsFile);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, the permissions are given to the player (seen while debugging), but whenever I ask if the player has a specific permission, it always returns true, even the rank doesn't give you the permission.

The permissions are loaded for each player when he joins and `MainPlayer` is an own class used to control the player from different aspects, the problem is not coming from this class.

Comment: It probably has to do with the permission plugin or the way you are using it, in which case I would ask on that plugin's Bukkit dev page or specifying the plugin.

Comment: It is my own plugin I coded myself, there is unfortunately nobody to ask

Comment: I found the problem, I forgot to de-op myself. Thanks for every help!

Answer (score 0):

There are different things that can go wrong when making a permissions plugin for bukkit, for example:

### Forgetting to de-op yourself

When you are a op, you basically have every permissions, except the permissions who define the default as something else.

To remove the op status from yourself, type ingame `/deop @p`

### Forgetting to call `player.recalculatePermissions()`

If you work with permissions that change during the lifetime of a player, you need to make sure that you call `player.recalculatePermissions()` to update the permissions.

### There is a spelling mistake in a permission

You should double check if the broken permission is correctly spelled, sometimes there may be even a mistake in the documentation of a plugin

### You are trying to set the `*` permission

There is no concept of a `*` permission in the bukkit permission system, the idea of a `*` permission comes from the old style permissions systems were `*` meant all permissions, this caused some problems in the past when it conflicted with permission removal, so bukkit decided to use the op/not-op system instead of  introducing a risky `*`. Some permission plugins decided to continue to use a `*` permission, and introduced code to get all registered permissions, but it still has its bugs.